# Proof of the theorem that there is no counterexample

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples

If $\rho(A) $ is a spectral radius and $ \|\cdot\|$ is norm, the relation $\rho(A) \leqslant \|A\| $ is always established.
I want to prove that if $\rho(A) <1$ then $ \|A\|<1$.
**Note that using the computer, I checked a large number of random matrices and there were no Counterexample. This is probably a mathematical theorem, but I can not prove it. please help. Thankful**

$$ $$

A friend found a counterexample for it so I change the condition to $0<\rho(A) <1$. Can the theorem be proved now?

Comment: It is not true, consider the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Under some conditions it will be true, for example if $A$ is symmetric because then $\rho(A)=\|A\|$

Comment: It might be true, but random examples rarely find counter examples for inequalities like this. That’s because you are seeking a boundary case, and those tend to be very thin in the domain of the question.

Comment: @leoli ٬ Yes you are right. In your opinion, if we change the condition to $0<\rho(A)<1$, will the theorem always be established?

Comment: @  Thomas Andrews , Yes you are right but I probably gave a math proof for that

Comment: No, $0<\rho(A)<1$ also is not enough, take $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$$ with $0<a<1$ then $\rho=a$ and $\|A\|=\sqrt{1+a^2}$

Comment: In finite dimensions what is true is that if $\rho(A)<1$ then there exists a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the corresponding induced norm of $A$ is $<1$.

Comment: @ leoli you're right. Your mind found a counterexample much faster than a computer :). Thankful

Comment: @copper.hat can you prove it? please

Comment: I will later when I get a chance.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $ V^{-1} A V = J$ where $J$ is the Jordan normal form. Write
$J= \Lambda+ T$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $T$ is strictly upper triangular.

Let $\|x\|_B = \|B^{-1} x\|$, where the latter is the Euclidean norm. It is easy to check that the corresponding induced norm is $\|A\|_B = \|B^{-1}A B \|$.

Note that if $A$ is diagonalisable (that is, $T =0$) then we see that
$\|A\|_V = \|\Lambda\| = \rho(A)$.

If $T \neq 0$ we need an adjustment. The idea is straightforward but the description is a little messy.

Let $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$, suppose all $\sigma_k>0$.
Note that $\Sigma \Lambda \Sigma^{-1} = \Lambda$ and
$[ \Sigma T \Sigma^{-1}]_{ij} = {\sigma_i \over \sigma_j} [T]_{ij}$.
Note that the latter term is always zero for $i \le j$.

Pick some $\epsilon>0$ and let $\sigma_1 = 1$, we will choose the remaining
$\sigma_k$ such that $|{\sigma_i \over \sigma_j} [T]_{ij}| < \epsilon$.
Suppose we have chosen $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_i$, then pick some $t >0$
such that $|{\sigma_i \over t} [T]_{ij}| < \epsilon$ for $j=i+1,...,n$ and
let $\sigma_{j+1} = t$.

Then we have
$\| A\|_{V \Sigma^{-1}} = \|\Sigma V^{-1} AV\Sigma^{-1}\| = \|\Sigma (\Lambda+T)\Sigma^{-1}\| \le \rho(A)+\| \Sigma T\Sigma^{-1} \|$
and it is straightforward to check that $\| \Sigma T\Sigma^{-1} \| \le n \epsilon$.

Comment: The summary of what you actually showed here is: 1. if $A$ is diagonalizable then there is an induced matrix norm such that $\| A \|=\rho(A)$. 2. if $A$ is not diagonalizable then for every  $\epsilon>0$ there exists an induced matrix norm $\| \cdot \|$ such that $\| A \| \leq \rho(A)+\epsilon$.